# How debug web application with maven Eclipse and glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven, glassfish

I create simple web application as maven project. Run mvn eclipse:eclipse and import it into Eclipse worck space. I also has a Glassfish. I run maven goal "clean install" and add properties:

```
maven.compilet.debug=true
maven.compilet.debuglevel=lines,vars,sources
```

I run this goal with properties from Eclipse and get war archive. Next I imported war into workspace then click "add and remove" on glassfish and during an "Publish to Glassfish" process project I get and error:

```
Unable to install breakpoint SomeClass s_ss_WeldSubdass due to missing line number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.

Reason:
Absent Line Number Information
```

I also check web server properties:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009
```

And check from admin console that **debug enabled on 9009 port.**

What is the problem?

**P.S.** I *can* create a breakpoint, but debug will be in unknow line.

Comment: Tried adding debug options to your compilation phase?  For javac it is `-g`.

Comment: What do you mean? Run javac? I want use maven build.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain your properties have the right names?

Comment: Your glassfish is local or remote?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding debug options to your maven compiler plugin configuration. By default its value is true, but perhaps your configuration for maven compiler plugin is not in a good way. It would be something like this,

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```